# check if api token exists in header in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to test if an API token exists in my API call. the headers being passed to are -

```
"host": [
          {
            "key": "Host",
            "value": "mydomain"
          }
        ],
        "x-api-key": [
          {
            "key": "x-api-key",
            "value": "mykey"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Now my code looks like

```
 // Check if apikey is a part of the headers 
    if ( !headers.hasOwnProperty('x-api-key') || headers['x-api-key'][0].value!="mykey") { 
        const body = 'Unauthorized';
        const response = {
            status: 401,
            statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
            body: body,
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
```

My If case errors out instead of sending 401 if the headers are missing `x-api-key` altogether

```
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
```

How should i change my condition so i can check for both the key/value pair and not have undefined errors incase of missing header key/value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your code to

```
 // Check if apikey is a part of the headers 
    if ( !headers.hasOwnProperty('x-api-key') || (headers.hasOwnProperty('x-api-key') && headers['x-api-key'][0].value!="mykey")) { 
        const body = 'Unauthorized';
        const response = {
            status: 401,
            statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
            body: body,
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
```

Your first condition checks if `x-api-key` exists in the headers. And the second condition checks the value for the `x-api-key`.

The way `OR` works is that it will stop its execution either at the first occurence of a `true` condition or will process each condition. Thus in your case, if `x-api-key` is not passed as a header, it still goes and checks the second condition. Since the `x-api-key` does not exist, it will not be able to read `[0]` of the property and hence the error.

However `AND` stops its execution at the first occurence of a `false` condition, and hence will never process the second condition if the `x-api-key` is not a part of the headers.